# Big Oh,small Oh and Big theta relations.

Tags: calculus, algorithms, asymptotics

If a function f(x)=O(g(x)), then there is a chance that f(x)=Ω(g(x)) and f(x)= ϴ(g(x)),but if f(x)=o(g(x)), is it possible that f(x)=Ω(g(x)),or f(x)=ω(g(x))?